# Spatial geometry for augmented reality applications

Tags: geometry, augmented-reality

Does anyone know any good book or web resource for geometric and mathematical fundamentals of augmented reality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good library for Augmented Reality:

[**ARToolKit**](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/)

Ports to various platforms:

[**NyARToolKit**](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wiki/index.php?FrontPage)

A simple but still impressive sample application using this library:

[**Project Marble**](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1326)

Answer (score 3):

A great read is [Chapter 10](http://www.dpfiles.com/dpfileswiki/index.php?title=Black_Art_of_3D_Game_Programming%2C_Chapter_10:_3D_Fundamentals) of the Black Art of 3d Game Programming.  All the AR/3D maths you'll ever need is there.

Once you've mastered this stuff, you'll be ready for 3d spatial projections etc, for AR/Target tracking.

Answer (score 3):

I can't point any specific book right now, but depending on your math background I'd suggest go in this order

1. Vector and Linear algebra, intermediate level, up to matrix operation, LU decomposition, cross product.
2. Projective geometry, up to  homogenious coordinates, planar homography
3. 3d graphics, viewing and projection matrix, frustum
4. Basics of image processing, thresholds, edge detection, line detection

After those 4 two you can understand rectangular marker tracking

5. Calculus of many variables, Fourier transform, DFT
6. Least squares method
7. Intermediate linear algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, SVD
8. Advanced numerical methods, nonlinear least-squares, Gauss-Newton, Levenberg-Marquardt
9. Advanced image processing, blob detection SIFT/SURF/FAST
10. Intermediate projective geometry: Essential and fundamental matrices, epipolar geometry
11. Bundle adjustment

After that you can understand markerless tracking

And some more advanced math which is used in cutting edge AR:

12. Understanding of basics of Lie groups and algebras
13. Statistics, robust estimators
14. Quaternions
15. Kalman filters
16. Clifford algebras (Geometric algebra) - generalization of quaternions
17. Wavelets
18. Advanced projective geometry (like trifocal tensor, 5-point algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following two books. Both are pricey but contain lots of really useful stuff in Projective Geometry which is what you need to know.

It's hard going though so unless you *really* want to understand the maths behind it you may want to use a third party library as suggested above.

[Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521540518) by Hartkey and Zisserman

and

[Three Dimensional Computer Vision: A Geometric Viewpoint](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0262061589) by Faugeras